# Ksql sbt dependency maven

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Maybe a naive question, but can anyone provide me the sbt dependency for KSQL?

I checked on Maven, but couldn't find any.

Is the dependency hosted some place other than Maven, if yes what would be the revolver I will have to add in my build.sbt file?

I'm trying to write a Scala app which uses Ksql to query on some kafka topics to create a dashboard with some metrics.

Answer (score 1):

None of the Confluent dependencies are in Maven Central

See 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/clients.html#maven-repository-for-jars

And I think this is the KSQL client target

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent.ksql</groupId>
        <artifactId>ksql-engine</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Example Java code - https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/tree/master/ksqldb-examples/src/main/java/io/confluent/ksql/embedded

You don't need to embed KSQL in your code, though. It's meant to run independently on the KSQL Server, which you can submit from code or use the KSQL CLI. In your application, you'd use a regular consumer or Kafka Streams API directly

I would suggest trying the new Scala Kafka Streams wrapper, too